# Adding temprary notification after clicking a button

Tags: javascript

I have a laravel project. I have button called "Copy Url" that copies the meeting id to clipboard. But i want to add temporarily notification after clicking the button. So i write some codes on javascript and copying is working right but somehow i can't able to show notifications. Here is my script:

```
var notyf = new Notyf();

document.querySelectorAll('.copy-url').forEach(function(link) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const url = this.getAttribute('data-url');
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(url)
            .then(() => {
                notyf.success('Your changes have been successfully saved!');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                notyf.error('You must fill out the form before moving forward');
            });
    });
});
```

and my meeting.blade.php :

```
<td>
     <div class="dropdown no-arrow mb-3">
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block copy-url" data-url="{{route('room', $meeting->meeting_id)}}">Copy URL</button>
     </div>
</td>
```

I tried several libraries like notyf, toaster etc. but i couldn't implement to this project. I added to an empty project, just index.html and script.js files; and it works but i am getting stuck on this project.

I tried adding cdn version of libraries.

I tried some other libraries sweetalert, toastr, notyf.

I tried even an alert in vanilla javascript but didn't show on our blade page. Still don't get it.

Comment: Is your script working? I mean, everything runs except the toast? You checked console for errors?

Comment: yes, i tried in an empty project it looks perfect. But in my laravel project, it does the copying part but not getting the notification so script is working theoratically. I checked the console but no errors. Edited: I mean i am running on live server and there is just this error: ``` caught (in promise) f: OneSignal: This web push config can only be used on https://live.smbwebcast.com. Your current origin is https://dev1.smbwebcast.com.
  ``` But i don't think that this is because of that.